# ArrayList clear deletes objects attributes from other ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

Object code

```
public class Example{
    private ArrayList<Point> points;

    public Example(ArrayList<Point> points)
       this.points = points;
    }
    //get and set here
}
```

Global code

```
 public static ArrayList<Example> examples = new ArrayList<>();
```

Main code

```
private ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();

private void addPoints(){
   this.points.add(new Point(num1,num2));
   //some more adds
}

private void newObject(){
   Global.examples.add(new Example(this.points));
   this.points.clear();
}
```

Calling code:

```
try {
    Global.vehicles.add(new Car((int)Math.random()*1+5,0.3,this.actualPoints.get(0).getX‌​(),this.actualPoints‌​.get(0).getY(),getCo‌​lor(),this.actualPoi‌​nts,"east","Car",nul‌​l,null,new VehicleBuffer()));
} catch (IOException ex) {
}
this.actualPoints.clear();
```

So everytime I add a new object to my Example ArrayList, it deletes the points ArrayList of all my objects, as well printing the toString of all the objects shows the same values for all the objects if I don't use the clear commands, they're not supposed to have their own personal ArrayList of points instead of using the same? It does have to do with the Example ArrayList being static? Since I need to get values from other objects but not using them I decided to make the array static

Comment: what do you mean by global code and main code

Comment: Please send the code that adds objects to the arraylists. From what I see, newObject method has this.points.clear() call, so if this method is being called, points arraylist will be cleared and that is as expected.

Comment: The Global is just a class with that line, the main code is a JPanel using that code

Comment: Don't post code in comments. You can see for yourself that it is completely illegible. It should have been in your question in the first place. Put it there now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not copying any `ArrayLists`, so there is only one. You need to fix `newObject()`:

```
private void newObject(){
   Global.examples.add(new Example(new ArrayList<Point>(this.points)));
   this.points.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Point> temp;

private void addPoints(){
   this.points.add(new Point(num1,num2));
   //some more adds
}

private void newObject(){
    temp = new ArrayList<Point>();
    Iterator<Point> it = this.points.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        temp.add(it.next());
    }
    Global.examples.add(temp);
    this.points.clear();
}
```

what happened was when you said `Global.examples.add(new Example(this.points));` you are actually copying the object `this.points` but not its contents in that case only a copy of the object is passed and stored in the list `examples` and when ever you clear `this.points` all its copies will also get cleared, to avoid this you need to declare a temporary list like temp and instantiate it with a new list every time you want to create a list and add it to examples.